# set value to texboxes with same name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, textbox

I have a number of textboxe as

```
   <td><input type="text" class="textbox" name="txtname[]" id="txtname[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="textbox" name="txtfname[]" id= "txtfname[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="textbox" name="txtmname[]" id="txtmname[]" /></td>
```

so i can have a table like form to enter values with number of rows of these textboxes.i need to set values for this texboxes.i have the row number which i need to set..but how can i get one row of these textboxes to set the value using id??

[image]

This is my form. number of rows are dynamic thats y i name them like that.i need to set a value for a circled textbox.How do i do it?

Comment: You question is very unclear, Please include all relevant code and show us what you have tried yourself so far. Also you have multiple elements with the same id, that is not good, use class for that.

Comment: i think you need to set row number as a index of array is not't it ?

Comment: You should not give array to id of an element...The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).you have to give unique id for each html element.

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do? Are you trying to tell remote server that a row's column has changed?

Comment: i need to identify that textbox with id..its  now is id="txtname[0]" ..is there a way i can get that box as $(''#textbox[0]").val();

Answer (score 0):

Your question is indeed pretty unclear but I assume that you just want to be able to manage component with dynamic id.

It is not a problem as you can simply use a variable for your id (it has to be a string at the end) but remember that your id has to remain unique.

Your algorythm could be :

```
for(i=0;i<txtname.length;i++) {
form+="<td><input type='text' class='textbox' name='txtname' id='txtname"+i+"' /></td>"
}
```

Comment: it's kinda clear that he says he wants to set the value of the textboxes by using the id.

Comment: this is the id='txtname"+i+"' of your textbox ..how will u set a value to it using jquery or js assuming u already know the value of i

Comment: Well to answer that question, it is true that we need to have more context around your code...

Answer (score 0):

As per Rule, "Id" should be unique across the current page,
So you have to use "class" in case of more then one DOM element.
so you can do this like:

```
var row =$(".textbox") 
row[0].value="FirstName"
row[1].value="MiddleName";
row[2].value="lastName"
```

if you have 4 row and dynamic(many) column:

```
var row = new Array(4);
for(loop to row length){
row[loop] = $(".textbox"+loop);//textbox0,textbox1,textbox2...
}
```

for accessing the value use  **row[column_index][row_index];** 
ex. row[0][2].value   give you MiddleName input field value

I hope you get this short explanation

Comment: you can use multi dimensional  element array if you have such row.

Answer (score 0):

As many have said your **id attribute** in html has to be unique so the use of an array name is not proper here please see here https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name.

Since this is table columns are generated dynamically I would recommend a naming convention on the table and then use that to find the current input you want. I have no idea how you access this information but my example below does this

Get table we are using.

Get the row for the index you want (Not sure how you determine this) in a comment you had '$(''#textbox[0]").val();' this index would be the 0...

On that row find the input by name and get its value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="datesheet">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" name="txtname[]" value="test0"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" name="txtfname[]"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" name="txtmname[]"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" name="txtname[]" value="test1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" name="txtfname[]"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" name="txtmname[]"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" name="txtname[]" value="test2"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" name="txtfname[]"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" name="txtmname[]"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    //Use an id on the table and get its rows
    let rows = $("#datesheet tr");

    //Now find the row you want
    let row_id = 1; // Not sure how you get this value.
    let current_row = rows[row_id];

    //Get the input you wants value
    let input_data = $(current_row).find("td input[name='txtname[]']").val()

    //Not sure what should be the same now.
    //If it is the other tds in this row then use selector above and set with val.
    //If is is other rows input with the same name... That would be a bit involved and I would need some time.

   //This is what other mean by unclear.


    alert(input_data);

</script>
```